# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error when using radio buttons to fill in a listbox

Tags: vb.net

I just wanted to ask if anyone knew why I might be getting the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` when I try to fill in a listbox for a playlist function on a media player I am trying to make.

```
Public Class PlaylistsForm

    Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        For Each Item As String In My.Settings.Playlist1
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Item)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton2.CheckedChanged
        Dim pl2 As New Setting(My.Settings.Playlist2)
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        For Each Item As String In My.Settings.Playlist2
            ListBox1.Items.Clear()
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Item)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton3_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton3.CheckedChanged
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        For Each Item As String In My.Settings.Playlist3
            ListBox1.Items.Clear()
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Item)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton4_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton4.CheckedChanged
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        For Each Item As String In My.Settings.Playlist4
            ListBox1.Items.Clear()
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Item)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton5_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton5.CheckedChanged
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        For Each Item As String In My.Settings.Playlist5
            ListBox1.Items.Clear()
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Item)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click
        ListBox1.SelectedItems.Clear()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Sorry - error happening here:
(Error is 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object')

```
    Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        For Each Item As String In My.Settings.Playlist1
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Item)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton2.CheckedChanged
        Dim pl2 As New Setting(My.Settings.Playlist2)
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        For Each Item As String In My.Settings.Playlist2
            ListBox1.Items.Clear()
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Item)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton3_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton3.CheckedChanged
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        For Each Item As String In My.Settings.Playlist3
            ListBox1.Items.Clear()
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Item)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton4_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton4.CheckedChanged
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        For Each Item As String In My.Settings.Playlist4
            ListBox1.Items.Clear()
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Item)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton5_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton5.CheckedChanged
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        For Each Item As String In My.Settings.Playlist5
            ListBox1.Items.Clear()
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Item)
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Is the error happening during the Add?, if so check the contents of your PlayLists. Also on Radiobutton 3,4,5 you are clearing out your list during every iteration of your `For Each` Loop leaving only the last Item in your `ListBox`.

Comment: Where is the error occurring?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could tell us which method and line the exception was happening on.

Comment: "Here's a wall of code. I'm getting this error. What could it be?" isn't a clear question. You have the exact information on where the exception is happening; is there some reason you don't want to share that information with us (especially as you're asking us to solve a problem for you)?

Comment: I would suggest checking the contents of your list, making sure that any references to an item within it are valid (item exists). Provide more information so that we can assist you.

Comment: On a side note, your radio buttons' `CheckedChanged` events are effectively only adding the the last `Item` in each playlist to `ListBox1` because the first operation in each `For` loop is clearing all the items in the listbox . Might be more effective to just add the last item without using a loop - IF that is your intent.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it very clear guys - I updated question.